# Moving Multiple Files of Same Type

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to move all .pbo files from one folder, into another folder. The following is my code:

```
For Each foundPBO As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
        downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@" & CurrentMod, _
        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pbo")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(foundPBO, downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@STHUD\Addons")
Next
```

It doesn't do anything when I run it, and the directory strings are correct (downloadDirectory is set correctly & CurrentMod is set correctly)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the help, although, I'm getting an error with conversion? Here's my following code, it doesn't get to the "3" message (debug):

```
Dim testDir As String = downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@STHUD\"
For Each foundPBO As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
        MsgBox("2"), _
        testDir, _
        MsgBox("3"), _
        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pbo")
        MsgBox("4")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(foundPBO, downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@STHUD\Addons\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(foundPBO))
        MsgBox("5")
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination path is wrong: you are intending to move `"dir_source\file_source.pbo"` to `"dir_dest\"`; but you should do: `"dir_dest\file_source.pbo"`. Just replace

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(foundPBO, downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@STHUD\Addons")
```

with:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(foundPBO, downloadDirectory & "\Mod Works\Process\@STHUD\Addons\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(foundPBO))
```

Bear in mind that there are `System.IO` equivalences for all what you are doing (getting files and moving them). You might prefer to rely on `System.IO`, rather than on `My.Computer.FileSystem`, as far as this Namespace contains methods to perform much more I/O-related actions (i.e., dealing with files, directories and paths).

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it and I get an error. Read the update above please :)

Comment: @user3054080 you are getting an error because your new code does not make any sense. Please, understand the suggested correction and remember that you can only ask one question per post. Perform the proposed modification in your original code and confirm that everything works fine.

Comment: @user3054080 You are welcome. I am happy to see that you were able to fix the last issues by your own.